# URL in backbone.js single page app gets way too long (~98'000 characters)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, single-page-application, backbone-routing

I have a JavaScript single page app (using backbone.js), where the app's state is stored as part of URL parameters. This webpage has a lot of checkboxes.

So if a user hits a URL like `http://my-app.org/project/#app/load?checkboxID[4053]=1&checkboxID[4054]=1&checkboxID[4055]=1&checkboxID[4056]=1&checkboxID[4057]=1&checkboxID[4058]=1&checkboxID[4059]=1...goes on and on, various further params...`

then the page configures itself (using Backbone.Router) with the given checkboxes selected. Notice the hash **#app** in the URL, meaning that the parameters are handled by the JavaScript app.

The problem is now that the app has now much more parameters than I previously thought of. Hence, with all checkboxes enabled, I get an URL that is about 98.000 characters long, whereas according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/1129950) it can only be 2.000 at most. Oops :-(

What's your advice to handle this? I thought maybe there is a smart way of "shortening"/"compressing" the URL string in JavaScript (like gzipping + base64 encoding the URL string), but even this does not shorten the URL enough to be under 2000 characters.

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of having the application state reflected in the URL? This will help identify the ideal solution.

Comment: You can use browser history in a single page app, in my case by utilizing [Backbone.Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router). That is, a user can use the Backwards / Forward buttons of a Browser. Users can even email the link, and (because the URL stores the app's state) it will open with the same settings/configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think passing the state of App via URL is good practice.
You could have a properly namespaced object to store the state.

```
var myApp = myApp || {};
myApp.state = myApp.state || {};
```

And when you are using URL to carry the state, just fill this object and use this around.

PS: This answer may not please you as you are looking for compression like things and would not like to change your code too much. Still a suggestion for you.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you reconfigure the url to read parameters as an array instead of individual items e.g.

```
checkboxId=[4053, 4054, 4054 ...]
```

That would save some characters and you can just loop through id's in said array.

If "40" is a common character, or if "4" is common you could even remove this from the value and prepend it when running the script?